# Webcam snapp-shot without showing Camera Window c# Vista, Windows 7

Tags: c#, camera

Hi all am creating an message application but as soon as the app snatch a picture from my webcam it starts showing a window to choice a camera know its only one camera installed

```
[DllImport("user32", EntryPoint = "SendMessage")]
static extern int SendMessage(int hWnd, uint Msg, int wParam, int lParam);
[DllImport("avicap32.dll", EntryPoint = "capCreateCaptureWindowA")]
static extern int capCreateCaptureWindowA(string lpszWindowName, int dwStyle,
    int X, int Y, int nWidth, int nHeight, int hwndParent, int nID);
const int WM_CAP_CONNECT = 1034;
const int WM_CAP_DISCONNECT = 1035;
const int WM_CAP_COPY = 1054;
const int WM_CAP_GET_FRAME = 1084;
```

This api works on windows xp with a service application so i created service app which pipe communicate with the appliaction and transfer the picture in bytes but note it only works on windows xp

how can i catch a webcam picture without this window am using some api in windows vista,7,8

Thanks B.

Answer (score 0):

The API you are referring to ([Video for Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd757708%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) is not supposed to operate without a window. The window however does not need to be visible, and you can move it out of work area too. It does not have to paint actually captured video as well, the window purpose is to communicate with the API. So it is usable in Window 7 too, provided of course that you have a well operating driver for these operating systems as well.

Other APIs you might want to look at are DirectShow and Media Foundation. DirectShow is the richest and best compatible throughout versions of Windows API, and you can do the task mentioned in the subject (capture without showing). From C# you typically work with it via [DirectShow.NET](http://directshownet.sourceforge.net/) library/binding and it has decent samples to look at on the website.